# Por que a sessão do express retorna 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express.js, requisição

Estou tendo problemas ao recuperar dados do `req.session`. Tenho um sub-roteador que gerencia a rota principal e utilizo um middleware para gerenciar a sessão. Eu acrescento os dados que quero gravar na sessão, porém quando o cliente acessa novamente a rota, o `req.session` parece ser resetado.

Arquivo `main.js`:

```
const sessionConfig = {
  id: uuid.v4(),
  secret: "1234",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 30,
    sameSite: true,
    secure: process.env.ENV === 'prod',
    sameSite: process.env.ENV === 'prod',
    httpOnly: true,
 }
}

router.use(session(sessionConfig))
antiSpam = (req,res,next)=>{
    let nextSend = req.session.nextSend
    let date = new Date()
    if(nextSend == undefined){
        next()
    }
    else{
        if (nextSend < date){
            next()
        }
        else{
            res.status(500)
            res.send()
        }
    }
}
router.post("/contato/send", antiSpam, (req,res)=>{
    data = req.body.data[0]
    Object.keys(data).map((obj)=>{
        
        if(data[obj] === ""){
            res.status(500)
            res.send()
        }
        if(obj == "tipo"){
            data[obj] = data[obj] == 'pac' ? "Paciente" : "Profissional"
        }
    })
    date = new Date()
    nextSend = new Date(date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 30))
    req.session.nextSend = nextSend
})
```

Como se pode ver, eu gravo a data atual que que o usuário acessou a rota `/contato/send` e antes do usuário entrar na rota eu tenho um middleware que checa se a data atual é maior que a data que foi acessada pela primeira vez. Eu armazeno essa data na variável `nextSend` e coloco-a no `req.session`, porém quando vou acessar `req.session.nextSend` ele retorna `undefined`.

P.S.: fiz alguns logs e aparenta que é gerada uma nova sessão para cada requisição feita.

Logs:

```js
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-11-22T14:43:20.239Z,
     originalMaxAge: 1800000,
     httpOnly: true,
     sameSite: true,
     secure: true },
  flash: {} }
Log do middleware antiSpam:
undefined
Log dentro da rota /contato/send:
2019-11-22T14:43:20.265Z
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-11-22T14:43:25.659Z,
     originalMaxAge: 1800000,
     httpOnly: true,
     sameSite: true,
     secure: true },
  flash: {} }
Log do middleware antiSpam:
undefined
Log dentro da rota /contato/send:
2019-11-22T14:43:25.662Z
```

Lembrando que, no primeiro acesso do usuário, o `req.session.nextSend` deve ser `undefined`, porém qualquer outro acesso depois do primeiro deve retornar a data que o cliente acessou pela primeira vez, na teoria pelo menos.

Comment: Tente mudar o `uuid.v4()` por alguma chave constante, como, por exemplo, `sid`. Resolve o problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duas coisas:

- Primeiro acho que nas config do cookie, o campo `secure` deve ser ajustado para `false`, pelo menos foi o que eu percebi no meu código. Ele funcionou e salvou a sessao quando o `secure: false`. O campo `secure` deve ser usado somente em conexoes `https`, se não, se a conexao for `http`, o cookie nao sera visualizado.
- segundo, eu corrigir o seu `if` de verificação de data para o padrão em milisegundos. Tente fazer algo parecido com meu código abaixo e tente novamente. Espero ter ajudado.

```js
    const sessionConfig = {
     id: "1",
     secret: "1234",
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: false,
     cookie: {
     maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 30,
     sameSite: true,
     secure: false, // ajustar para false em conexoes HTTP
     sameSite: true,
     httpOnly: true
     }
    };

    app.use(session(sessionConfig));

    app.get(
     "/oi",
     (req, res, next) => {
      let date = Date.now();
      let nextSend = req.session.nextSend;
      if (!nextSend) {
       return next();
      }
      console.log(nextSend, date)
      if (nextSend < date) { // para este if, ambas as datas devem estar em milisegundos
       console.log("eh menor!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Pode prosseguir.");
       return next();
      }
      console.log("===== Data atual:", new Date(Date.now()), "\n");
      console.log("===== Proxima data de envio:", new Date(req.session.nextSend), 
       "\n");
      return res.json({ message: "PERA AI" });
    },
    (req, res) => {
      req.session.nextSend = Date.now() + 18000; // 18 segundos apenas para teste
      res.sendFile("index.html", {
       root: path.join(__dirname, "views")
      });
     }
    );
```

Saida: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou!!! Valeu!